# Worklight: Windows 8 store certification issues for UTF-8 file encoding

Tags: windows-8, ibm-mobilefirst

We have developed a hybrid app using worklight 6.1. We have set up our environment in eclipse juno.
While verifying the app using windows app cert kit, we are getting following error -

The UTF-8 file encoding test detected the following errors:
...\www\default\worklight\worklight.css is not properly UTF-8 encoded. Re-save the file as UTF-8 (including Byte Order Mark).
and many more such errors for dojo files as well.

Is there any settings, that we can do in eclipse, that will make all the files in app to use UTF-8 encoding.
I tried Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace : Text file encoding and set it to use "UTF-8". But this didn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update:*

It appears that for a Windows 8 store application, [HTML/CSS/JS files must be encoded in UTF-8 with BOM marker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj657973.aspx#file_encoding_test), however Worklight Studio does not generate these files with the BOM marker.

To have this fixed, you'll need to [create a PMR](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21507639) so that the development team could investigate &  provide a fix.

In the meanwhile you can [follow Microsoft's suggestion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj657973.aspx#file_encoding_test):

> **Corrective Action**
>   Open the affected file and select Save As from the
>   File menu in Visual Studio. Select the drop-down control next to the
>   Save button and select Save with Encoding. From the Advanced save
>   options dialog, choose the Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) option and
>   click OK.

---

*Previously:*

If you have already created your Worklight project and *then* changed the encoding to UTF-8, this will not help this pre-existing project.

Delete the native windows8\native folder and re-build the project in Eclipse. This will then re-generate the native folder with the mentioned CSS file, in UTF-8 encoding.

I've tested this, and the file was created as mentioned, encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks Idan. I tried this option as well, but still windows app cert kit is giving the same error. I guess, it is expecting the files to be encoded with UTF-8 including BOM.

Comment: @VijayPatil, please see my updated answer. To have this fixed, please open a PMR. Until then you can continue with the workaround. When opening the PMR, mention this question.